# cvConvertScale not Working as Expected?

Tags: opencv

I am running the simple code below and expecting the depth of o to become 32. 
But it still remains 8. Am I missing something ???

```
  IplImage *o = cvCreateImage(cvSize(100,100), 8,1);
  IplImage *n = cvCreateImage(cvSize(100,100), 32,1);

  cvConvertScale(o,n,1.0,0.0);

  printf("The depth of o is %d\n", o->depth);
  printf("The depth of n is %d\n", n->depth);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALright, the behavior correct.
The datatype in the source image is not converted into the datatype of the destination.

Just that the source is multiplied with the scaling constant and cast into the type of the destination, and stores the result in the destination.

So there is no change in the types of either the source or the destination.
Just the data in the destination changes for a scaling constant other than 1.0

Answer (score 1):

What would make more sense is:

```
  IplImage *in8u = cvLoadImage( filename, 1); // always uint8, and in this case 3 channel
  IplImage *in32f = cvCreateImage(cvSize(100,100), IPL_DEPTH_32F ,3); // whatever you choose

  cvConvertScale(in8u,in32f,1.0,0.0);

  printf("The depth of in8u is %d\n", in8u->depth);
  printf("The depth of in32f is %d\n", in32f->depth);
```

Now you have the 8-bit input file's data as the 32-bit float data